# Migrating SSIS and SQL Server data from AWS to Azure

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, azure

I have amazon EC2 instance on AWS where SQL server is installed. I want to migrate SQL Server data and SSIS packages to Azure VMs.

I can not effort any loss of information.

What would be the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Azure Blob Storage as the transport.

SQL Server out of the box can create backups and can restore databases directly to/from Azure Blob containers

For instance:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL sql_backup_credential
--storage account name:
WITH IDENTITY='your-storage-account',
--storage account key from portal:
SECRET = 'pvv99UFQvuLadBEb7ClZhRsf9zE8/OA9B9E2ZV2kuoDXu7hy0YA5OTgr89tEAqZygH+3ckJQzk8a4+mpmjN7Lg=='


BACKUP DATABASE Test
TO URL = N'https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/your-container/test.bak'
WITH credential = 'sql_backup_credential';
```

So, this way all user databases + SSISDB can be transferred from one isolated box to another.

Of course, Firewall settings of SQL Server VMs to allow outbound and inbound connections for HTTPS.